# How to find (and interpret) outliers in set of time series data?

Tags: time-series, outliers, data-preprocessing

I face with a problem of doing a time series forecasting on multivariate data in the form where different entities have their own 100-day (daily) series of 10 variables, and I'm expected to predict 10-day steps of the response variable in the future.

Now, I'd like to handle "outliers" in the data, and I wonder how to interpret "outliers" in this context. In the case of non-time-series data I'm more confident (of applying Isolation Forest or any other multivariate outlier detection algorithm), but in case of this set of series that is not applicable, because in this case we must consider the respective time series in whole (that is, either the whole series is outlier or inlier, not just one or two steps in the series).

I tried to aggregate each variable of the respective series (like mean/median) and find outliers in these aggregated data, but this is somewhat misleading, as a series could have extremes while it has non-extreme mean/median). Also, I considered qualifying whole series as outlier if there is only one outlier time step among the time flow, but this also seems simplistic, and anyway, too high proportion of the original series would be "outlier" in this way.

What is a proper approach in this problem? Or maybe I should just forget finding outliers at all and try to model on the original data irrespective of the extreme values?